# DataFrame' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, pandas

When trying to convert Data Frame (data_df) to text or string, I get  the following error:

```py
df2.text = data_df.text.apply(func=stop)
```

yields

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-2a9ac16c9bf8> in <module>()
----> 1 df2.text=data_df.text.apply(func=stop)#thanks

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5139             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5140                 return self[name]
-> 5141             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5142 
   5143     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Is there a column called Text? Or are your trying to convert the entire dataframe to strings?

Comment: Yes trying to convert the entire dataframe into string. The dataframe has only one column

Answer (score 0):

You should be using "str" and not "text".
Try:

```
df2 = data_df[0].astpe(str).apply(stop)
```

Comment: df2=data_df.astype(str).str.apply(stop)                                                                                               AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-26b3f8b88900> in <module>()
----> 1 df2=data_df.astype('str').str.apply(stop)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
  
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: What is the name of your dataframe column?

Comment: Having default column name - 0

Comment: Thanks !!! But now getting the issue with apply atribute-.............................................df2 = data_df[0].astype(str).str.apply(stop) .....AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'apply'